# BorderBrush and Background not match

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, background, gradient, brush

I am having a problem with BorderBrush and Background. They both are set to the same gradient but as border starts higher, they don't match. How do I make it match? These are 5 buttons in the image:

[image]

Edited: I need border for rounded corners. It's not in the picture but I need 'em.

Comment: Can't you just use a single outer element with the gradient as background and padding?

Comment: Do you actually require the border? Because if not then it could be removed, which would eradicate the problem.

Comment: btw, no need to use imageshack; SO has a special account with imgur that can handle the punishment.  Use the image link in the editor to upload an image next time.

Comment: Also, why not skip the border in the first place?  Set its width to 0.

Comment: The above's are correct, just remove the border. The reason you're getting the offset is because your gradient is the same, yet the shapes are different sizes (if you take the border as a rectangle also). You'd need to account for this in your gradient if you wanted to get it working, although like peeps say, it's easier just to make your element bigger and remove the border.

Comment: Forgot to mention. This is a test but I need border for rounded corners.

Comment: @Will I wondered what SO used for image hosting +1 for imgur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make it harder on yourself?  To achieve this (keep rounded corners), you can do one of two things:  Adjust the border gradient (trial and error, most likely) or you will have to change the button's [Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx) so that the face of the button is represented by a Border that has radiused corners (with a border of thickness 0) and a Background of your gradient.

Of course, since the [Button template is very complex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) you'll have to reproduce all the animations, overlays etc on your new template.